# Virtual Env can't be activated (Windows)

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtual

I created a Virtual env with the command

```
virtualenv mypython3
```

I changed to it's Directory:

```
cd C:\Users\A704601\Documents\Virtualenv
```

Then I tried to activate it:

```
"C:\Users\A704601\Documents\Virtualenv\mypython3\Scripts\activate.bat"
```

But it didn't work. I don't have (mypython3) before the C:
But it didn't show an error. It just does nothing.

I don't know why it's not working. Here is the activate.bat:

```vb
@echo off

set "VIRTUAL_ENV=C:\Users\A704601\Documents\Virtualenv\mypython3"

if defined _OLD_VIRTUAL_PROMPT (
    set "PROMPT=%_OLD_VIRTUAL_PROMPT%"
) else (
    if not defined PROMPT (
        set "PROMPT=$P$G"
    )
    if not defined VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT (
        set "_OLD_VIRTUAL_PROMPT=%PROMPT%"
    )
)

if not defined VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT (
    set "PROMPT=%PROMPT%"
)

REM Don't use () to avoid problems with them in %PATH%

if defined _OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME goto ENDIFVHOME
    set "_OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME=%PYTHONHOME%"
:ENDIFVHOME

set PYTHONHOME=

REM if defined _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH (
if not defined _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH goto ENDIFVPATH1
    set "PATH=%_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH%"
:ENDIFVPATH1

REM ) else (

if defined _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH goto ENDIFVPATH2
    set "_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH=%PATH%"

:ENDIFVPATH2

set "PATH=%VIRTUAL_ENV%\Scripts;%PATH%"
```

I don't know why it's not working. I'm using Windows 10 and Python 3.6 and the latest version of virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you created a virtual environment folder called "mypython" and then it seems like you have renamed this folder to "mypython3". Please delete your virtualenv and try again or just create another environment:

```
cd C:\Users\A704601\Documents\Virtualenv
virtualenv anothertry
"C:\Users\A704601\Documents\Virtualenv\anothertry\Scripts\activate.bat"
```

Comment: No it was just a spelling mistake in Stack. It was mypython3 all along. I also created a bunch of virtual envs to make sure it isn't a spelling mistake